# Sql plus doesn't show English

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, ora-12560

SQL plus doesn't show English as shown here

[image: sql plus]

and it also returns error for system user name and password, even the user name and password are correct!
The error is  ORA-12560:TNS:protocol adapter error, what should I dخ??

Comment: Have you set ORACLE_HOME to the correct path? Is TNS_ADMIN set or is your tnsnames.ora found at ORACLE_HOME/network/admin or TNS_ADMIN?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem occurs when console codepage mismatch Oracle client **NLS_LANG** parameter.

NLS_LANG parameter you can set changing Windows-registry key *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\NLS_LANG* or defines environment variable NLS_LANG.

Example of setting parameter for console session:

```
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1
```

Codepage of console you can set execute this:

```
chcp 850
```